# How to open a browser in PHP?

Tags: php, apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3, userscripts

Im here to ask a probably dumb question again. This is related to my previous [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4447593/how-to-send-a-flv-format-data-in-bytearray-using-urlloader-to-a-php-script).

I current found a way for flash/flex to send a video file(in byteArray) to php. Where php receives and writes it in the local sytem then sends it to the youtube server automatically trhu a script.
This is all backend though I have no way to check if the video file was uploaded succesfully in youtube than to check it manually in youtube.

So im thinking of a new php script where it will receive and write the video file from flash. Then opening a browser window where it will automatically upload the video and at the same time track it thru the browser of its status using debug prints perhaps.

Im barely still learning php. I tried to do some research on this but found no success. Hope you can help me guys. Thanks.

Comment: YouTube's API does allow you to check the status of a video. There's no need to try to retrieve the HTML contents of a YouTube page to try to guess if the video is working correctly.

Answer (score 4):

PHP code runs on your web server. It's code running on another computer. It can't open anything on YOUR computer. If it could, I would also be able to open windows on YOUR computer from the one I'm typing on, and you'd have some serious problems. By tomorrow everyone in the world would have their computers either taken over or destroyed by other random people on the internet.

Answer (score 0):

PHP is server side, you can't  directly use any PHP code to control browser activity on client side.
You need to resort to client side technology such as Flash and JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

echo "XXX window.open('URL');XXX'

XXX = script tag from Java, I can't post html tags